# OpenCV: Conversion of vector<vector<Point>> to vector<Mat>, problems with call by reference

Tags: c++, opencv, scope, mat, pass-by-reference

I was trying to extract contour lines from an image, using OpenCV 2.4.9.
The `findContours` function does most of the work, but it returns the contour lines
as type `vector < vector < Point > >`.
I need to convert them to type `vector < Mat >` for later uses.
I used a constructor of the `Mat` class to do the job and everything works fine until I pass the result from one function to the other via call by reference. 
The following code reproduces the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void getCont(Mat& img, vector<Mat>& cLines, int thresh)
{
    //binarize the image
    Mat imgBin;
    threshold(img, imgBin, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    //find contour lines
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(imgBin, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    //convert vector<vector<Point>> to vector<Mat>
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        cLines.push_back(Mat(contours[i])); 

    cerr << "cLines[0] in getCont:\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].rows: " << cLines[0].rows << "\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].cols: " << cLines[0].cols << "\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].channels(): " << cLines[0].channels() << "\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].type(): " << cLines[0].type() << "\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].row(0): " << cLines[0].row(0) << "\n";
    cerr << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("leaf.jpg", 0);
    int thresh = 124;

    vector<Mat> cLines;
    getCont(img, cLines, thresh);

    cerr << "cLines[0] in main:\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].rows: " << cLines[0].rows << "\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].cols: " << cLines[0].cols << "\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].channels(): " << cLines[0].channels() << "\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].type(): " << cLines[0].type() << "\n";
    cerr << "cLines[0].row(0): " << cLines[0].row(0) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The error occurs in main, in the line preceding the return statement, when I try to print out the first row of the first element of `cLines`. For different input images, I either get a message, which tells me, that the .exe is not working properly and has to quit or the values are actually printed out, but they differ from the output of the `getCont` function (in main, I get negative values, so it looks like there is some overflow). I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express on Windows 8, 64 bit machine (but I'm using the x86 DLL libraries of OpenCV). Can anyone reproduce the error on a different system?

I thought there was some implicit type cast, so I printed out the size and type of `cLines` in `getCont` and `main`, but the results are the same. The error does not occur, when I put the code of the `getCont` function into `main`, so that I avoid the additional function call.
Also, everything works fine, when I replace the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    cLines.push_back(Mat(contours[i]));
```

by the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    vector<Point> currPts = contours.at(i);
    Mat currLine(currPts.size(), 1, CV_32SC2);
    for (int j = 0; j < currPts.size(); j++)
    {
        currLine.at<Vec2i>(j, 0).val[0] = currPts.at(j).x;
        currLine.at<Vec2i>(j, 0).val[1] = currPts.at(j).y;
    }
    cLines.push_back(currLine);
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration of `cLines` be similar to `Mat currLine(currPts.size(), 1, CV_32SC2);`? In your main, nowhere does it say `CV_32SC2`.

Comment: @a-Jays: Thanks for your answer. I do not explicitly set the type when I declare cLines, but the output of cLines[0].type() is 12 (which is CV_32SC2 in the enum), both in main and in getCont.

Comment: Works well for me. Did you load the image successfully? You can try to `imshow` it to verify.

Comment: Yes, I checked whether the image was loaded succesfully. It's interesting to hear that it works on your system. The strange thing  happens when cLines is passed from getCont to main.

Comment: @herohuyongtao I think you got lucky.  The problem is that the `Mat` constructor does not copy the data by default and the `vector` goes out of scope when `getCont` returns.  I see negative numbers, but I can see how the right data might still be in memory even thought the buffer has been deallocated.  Something new for your [knowledge points](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.com/2012/09/opencv-knowledge-points.html)?  ;)

Comment: @chappjc You got me. ;)

Comment: @chappjc Thank you very much! :-)  I just tried it and it works. Now I understand what went wrong.

Comment: Great, glad to help!  Please upvote when you are able.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the right constructor but incorrectly accepting the default for the second parameter.  The declaration for the `Mat` constructor taking `std::vector` as an input:

```
//! builds matrix from std::vector with or without copying the data
template<typename _Tp> explicit Mat(const vector<_Tp>& vec, bool copyData=false);
```

The [online documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) for the cv::Mat constructors states:

> `copyData` – Flag to specify whether the underlying data of the STL vector or the old-style CvMat or IplImage should be copied to (true) or shared with (false) the newly constructed matrix. When the data is copied, the allocated buffer is managed using Mat reference counting mechanism. While the data is shared, the reference counter is NULL, and you should not deallocate the data until the matrix is not destructed.

You need to do:

`cLines.push_back(Mat(contours[i],true));`

Otherwise the vector will go out of scope when you return to `main` and the data buffer for the `vector<vector<Point>> contours` declared in `getCont` will have been deallocated.

For `cv::Vec`, `Point_`, and `Point3_`, the default for `copyData` is true, unlike for `std::vector`.